# Using FreeCAD to retrieve planform area of aircraft

Tags: cad, autocad

I have a science project I'm working on that involves a need to know the planform area of airplanes. The planform area is the area of an airplane as viewed from above the plane.

I was told by someone on the Aviation StackExchange that I could try using a CAD program to figure this out. So, I downloaded FreeCAD. I have some .dwg and .dxf files from Boeing and Airbus which I want to use to calculate the planform area. But, I've loaded one of these files into FreeCAD and I can't seem to figure out how to do this, since I have no experience with FreeCAD.

Can someone give me step-by-step instructions? [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GzFlJvpigbHfFxhfvbiOMt7vKpVPJu4X?usp=sharing) are two example files. The .dxf is for a Boeing plane, the .dwg is for the Airbus

Comment: Never used FreeCAD but in AutoCAD there are measurement tools such as length, radius, angle, as well as perimeter and area. You connect line to line and trace out some enclosed area and it spits back the perimeter and area.

Comment: @DKNguyen Does AutoCAD cost money?

Comment: Most versions certainly do. I do not know if there is a lite version. There are trials. Or at least there used to be. I don't know about now. FreeCAD should have something similar in any case.

Comment: Have you done a simple Google search for "plan area Airbus ..." etc? Any technical documents come up? did for me...

Comment: As far as CAD programs go, FreeCAD is easily one of the worst and feature-free ones available.

Comment: There are 30 day trial versions of all AutoCAD products.

Comment: does plan form area include engines?  or the small triangular area on the trailing edge of the wings?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the area of any irregular shape can be calculated by breaking it up into known shapes (eg pixels) and multiplying their number by their dimensions.

It should be simple enough to open an image in photoshop or another program and get a pixel count of the silhouette. Then convert the pixel dimensions to area.

I don't know how to do this in Freecad, but I don't see a need for CAD software for this problem. Any drawing software that gives a pixel count would do the job. It's a 2d problem, not 3d

But,

this would only give you the area of your pictures silhouette, you'd have to scale that up if you need the actual plane silhouette size.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a minor problem with the precision of the line work in your drawings.  When I open the dwg file I noted the disconnect at some points in your drawing such as this:

[image]

The wing tip to wing tip measurement is 63998.021 units.  I have no idea if this is to scale or not.  The unconnected line is out by 0.356 which may be insignificant units, but prevents the use of some nice cad commands that make life easier.

so after connecting the unconnected line ends, I used a command that is available in Civil3D, and I also think perhaps Architectural desktop, called LINEWORKSHRINKWRAP.  It creates a closed polyline around the outside perimeter of connected lines.

[image]

Note I deleted the excess interior line works and did a minor edit of some final line works where the script cut some corners.

I then used the AREA command on the closed polyline and got:

[image]

Now this number only works if the original plan was drawn to scale.  Since there are no dimensions visible, and with out some reference points to verify, its impossible to say if the number is accurate.